# Is $0 = 0^1 = 0^2 \times 0^{-1}?$

Tags: number-theory

Does the above equation follow? Conversely, can you say $0^2 \times 0^{-1} = 0^1 = 0$? I apologize if this is a stupid question but it just popped in my mind.

Comment: May be of interest: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548/explanation-of-method-for-showing-that-frac00-is-undefined

Answer (score 4):

$0^{-1}$ doesn't exist because we can't find another number $x$ such that $0x=1$.

We do have
$$0=0^{1}$$