# is $\frac{0}{0}$ indeterminate or undefined?

Tags: definition, real-numbers, indeterminate-forms

I know in calculus the form $\frac{0}{0}$ is indeterminate.but if it is not calculus is it still indeterminate or undefined in the real number field?

P.S. I know that $\frac{1}{0}$ is undefined whether it is calculus or normal arithmetic in the real number system. but in the projectively extensive real number system, $\frac{1}{0}=\infty$ but in this system what would be $\frac{0}{0}$ it becomes $0*\infty$ also an indeterminate form. in that system the problem $\frac{1}{0}$ is solved but $\frac{0}{0}$ remains.

P.P.S some answers in the question which has been identified as a duplicate of my Q state the $\frac{0}{0}$ is indeterminate. but in Wikipedia page(division by zero) states it is undefined. and that question was asked not to clarify this ambiguity(indeterminate or undefined) and there is no clear answer to my problem.

Comment: idk exactly what it is but i think it is  a matter of convenience as both are usually avoided in computations

Comment: @GNUSupporter It does not answers to my problem

Comment: Why this question having eleven answers doesn't answer your question?  Your question is "is $\frac00$ indeterminate or undefined". Lehs' answer suggests "In the ordinary number systems division by zero is undefined.", and Bram28's answer suggests that "we say that $\frac00$ is 'indeterminate'"

Comment: @GNUSupporter there is no clear reason in Leh's answers why he says it is undefined instead of indeterminate. and the same thing for Bram28

Comment: Bram28's answer (with the highest score) clearly explains the reason.  You may refer to the sentence preceding "we say that $\frac00$ is 'indeterminate".

Comment: @GNUSupporter it also states "But that still doesn't mean that $\frac{0}{0}$ is defined!" so is it indeterminate or undefined? is it both?

Comment: [Indeterminate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate) has several senses.  "but if it is not calculus", I assume the one in formal algebra: the connective "instead" in Bram28's answer suggests that "0/0 is an indeterminate" because "we don't have a unique solution to $0x=0$".  We can *infer* from the tone and the word "still" of your quoted sentence that Bram28 thinks that $\frac00$ is *undefined*.  P.S. The usual practice in math is to use words rather than symbols, so the words and their tone count.

Comment: @GNUSupporter actually i prefer a clear and explained answer insted of "infer from tone" type answer

Comment: Then another related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/548/290189

Comment: How do you distinguish indeterminate from undefined?

Comment: @GNUSupporter ok now in that question, it says $\frac{0}{0}$ is undefined. and previous Bram28's answer suggests it is indeterminate. so what is it? this is exactly where I am confused.

Comment: @copper.hat as per my knowledge if it is not defined in the context it is undefined. if the result may vary with the conditions it is indeterminate. but i want to know the exact meaning of $\frac{0}{0}$

Comment: Do you understand the role of the English word "instead" in Bram28's answer?  It's a device connecting previous arguments to the conclusion.  I've given you a link to a Wiki article about indeterminate (I'm not supposed to do so.), and you asked me "what is it".  I am confused at what you are confused.

Comment: I think you are splitting hairs on a red herring...

Comment: The term "indeterminate" has no standard meaning, outside of "indeterminate forms" in calculus.  So your question is meaningless unless you say what you mean by "indeterminate".

Answer (score 1):

Unlike $0\cdot\infty$, which is 0 if it's zero measure times infinite value (or zero value times infinite measure ) but otherwise not defined, one never attributes a value to $0/0$.  It's BOTH indeterminate AND undefined.

To be specific it's indeterminate because if you tried to give a meaning to it, you could justify anything.  It's undefined because (unlike with $0\cdot\infty$) one doesn't define it by convention either.

Comment: can you give me some recommendation to further reading? and what is your source?

Comment: For $0\cdot\infty=0$ in a measure theory context, any good book on real analysis using measure theory will cover that, for example Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*.  As for never giving a value to $0/0$, I have a lot of mathematical experience and I've never seen $0/0$ or $\infty - \infty$ given values, whereas it is occasionally useful to define other expressions one doesn't usually define like $0\cdot\infty=0$ in a measure theory context or $0^0=1$ in a power series or polynomial context or $1/0=\infty$ in the case you cited.