# A problem with 0/0=0

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So what is the problem/contradiction
If I state I can divide by 0 but the number will be 0 I tried a few thing but didn't find a problem

Comment: Division is best understood in terms of multiplication since that's exactly where it comes from. The quantity $\frac{a}{b}$ is the *unique* number $x$ such that $a = bx$. Is there a unique number $x$ such that $0 = 0x$?

Comment: When we say $a/b = c$ , we mean we have to find a number $c$ such that when multiplied by $b$ , would give us $a$. In case of $0/0$ , we need a number $x$ such that $x\times0 = 0$,  but it is true for all values of $x$.

Comment: Note that $\frac 0 0 =c \implies 0=c\cdot 0=0$ for any $c$.

Comment: Not clear... "divide by $0$" has no meaning: this is why $\dfrac 0 0$ is *undefined*. We divide by two when we cut in a half; we divide by one when we do not divide at all. Thus, there is nothing "less than" not divide at all.

Comment: $\frac{0}{0}+\frac{1}{1}$ is what then?  If addition worked for rationals as it should usually, noting that $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}=\frac{ad+bc}{bd}$ we would have had $1 = 0+1=\frac{0}{0}+\frac{1}{1}=\frac{0\cdot 1+0\cdot 1}{0\cdot 1} = \frac{0}{0}=0$

Comment: Exactly which issue you butt against depends on your definitions. Most importantly, when you write a fraction $\frac ab$, what does that _mean_? What fundamental property should $\frac ab$ have that makes it have the value it does?

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548/explanation-of-method-for-showing-that-frac00-is-undefined

Answer (score 2):

Let $\frac 0 0=0$

then $\frac 0 0+\frac ab=0+\frac ab=\frac ab$

However  $\frac 0 0+\frac ab=\frac {a\cdot 0+b\cdot 0} {0\cdot b}=\frac 0 0$

Which implies $\frac ab=0$.

Let $a=2$ and let $b=1$.

Contradiction , as it implies $2=0$.

Furthermore, Consider the group of integers defined w.r.t multiplication. In any group, there exists only a single identity element and in the group of integers /0. It is 1. However by introducing 0*0^(-1)=0, it implies 0 is the identity element. This would also mean that there are 2 multiplicative identities for a single group. The whole group theory will be in big trouble as a result and we would get a lot of contradictions too.